# Change in Signature in `FunctionComponent` is making upgrading a lot more work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in `@types/react@16.14.5`, the `FunctionComponent` type is as follows:

```
  interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {  
(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;  
propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;  
contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;  
defaultProps?: Partial<P>;  
displayName?: string;  
}
```

where as in `@latest` is looks like

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
        displayName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

Because `P` not longer defined as `PropsWithChildren<P>`, it means any component that uses `FunctionComponent` no longer has an defined `children` prop, meaning that I get type errors for every component defined with this type that has children.

This means a lot of work, across libraries and a large webapp, to update all the types to include `children` explicitly.

Is there a way around this?